# using DECIMAL(,) argument in pSQL to create a table, throwing an error

Tags: sql, database-design, decimal

**My data for my columns looks like this (example of decimal input):**

country:            Belize
hdi:                0.716
education_index:    0.695
health_expend_2017: 10.6
life_expectancy:    74.6
gdp_per_capita:     7005
gross_gdp:          5488.6
below_poverty_line: 32.5
gender_ineq:        0.429

**And I'm trying to upload into my table that I create here in SQL:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE metrics (country TEXT, hdi DECIMAL(4,3),
education_index
DECIMAL(4,3), health_expend_2017 DECIMAL(3,1), life_expectancy DECIMAL(4,1), gdp_per_capita INTEGER, gross_gdp DECIMAL(5,1), below_poverty_line DECIMAL(3,1), gender_ineq DECIMAL(4,3));
```

My understanding of DECIMAL is the first argument is for how many total digits (before and after decimal point combined) and the second argument is for precision (how many digits after decimal point)

But it is getting mad at me for the data type this is the error I am getting

ERROR:  numeric field overflow

**Am I not using DECIMAL correctly?**

Comment: The data you showed should not be causing this error, leading me to suspect that the problem lies elsewhere in your data (not shown here).  I would suggest checking your source for the problem.

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen said, examine your code for the error. One thing to check is that you have no error in assigning the corresponding values to their fields in your code. (Ee.g. make sure you haven't accidentally assigned life_expectancy to the health_expend_2017 field.)